# AWS ECS microservices route

Tags: amazon-web-services, routes, microservices, devops

I have an ECS cluster in AWS and can't find a solution for the microservices to be accessed, like:

domain.com/service1 or domain.com/service2

Where each service is a different task definition or container.

The domain is handled via Cloudfront.

Does anybody know if this is possible only via AWS services? Can the microservices be routed in AWS via /path or /microservice. Can this be done via API gateway?

Tried to find a solution from cloudfront and API gateway, but I may not be doing something right.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/field-notes-integrating-http-apis-with-aws-cloud-map-and-amazon-ecs-services/) is a good reference blog specifying HTTP API, CloudFront, API Gateway and ECS tasks.
It provides context on routing a specific path to a specific ECS task